# How to add postgresql to OpenShift Spring app?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, openshift

I have created the **Spring** quick-start app on **OpenShift** and it was working all fine showing a web page for user registration, except it doesn't remember the new members after restart. I was thinking, that it's because I don't have a true database.  So I added a ***postgresql-9.2*** cartridge.  So my question is how to accurately configure ***postgresql*** to **OpenSift Spring** application, so that this web server can store the data that persist after restart.

### **First problem**

I created the OpenShift project in Eclipse, but the `pom.xml` doesn't have the ***postgresql*** items.  That meas, I couldn't see ***postgresql*** dependencies in the Maven dependencies.  I believe that in other applications I created such as ***JBoss EAP 6*** I can find the Maven dependencies if I add the cartridges.  What is the correct way to add *postgresql* to the project?

### **Second problem**

There is a README.md file which says

> Edit `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` to use the
>   appropriate datasource (java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS or
>   java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS):
>
> ```
> <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS</jta-data-source>
> ```

So I did.  But I think this README is missing something.  I build the project and see `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` has error. The content is

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
            <module name="com.h2database.h2"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I was thinking the problem is that the database h2 is now removed from the `persistence.xml`, but I don't know how to add the corresponding postgresql module here.  I am a completely newbie on Spring/OpenShift/Postgresql, so can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The second problem can be fixed by changing the "urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0" to "urn:jboss:deployment-structure:2.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Question:**
For spring-quick-start app, you don't need to get Maven dependencies for the Postgresql or Mysql.  You just need to follow the Readme to change the persistence.xml.

**Second Question:**
If you don't build locally, there is no need even to change 1.0 to 2.0.  Openshift will take that.

Comment: I followed the Readme.  This time it worked.  Thanks.